# How to configure parity to work with the ETC chain?

Tags: the-dao, ethereum-classic, parity

I have some ETC/DAO-C funds that I want to [claim](https://daoc.codetract.io), so I'm interested in running a parity node to do this. How can I configure parity to follow the ETC chain?

Comment: consider to accept one of the answers bellow

Answer (score 7):

it is indicated in the [doc](https://wiki.parity.io/Chain-specification) that 
Parity  supports ETC   through the CLI argument `--chain classic.`

Comment: ok thanks, and will this use a different path for the chain? (so that I can switch to ETH later without conflicts)

Comment: use different folder for the chain

Comment: don't understand your answer, is that imperative tense?

Comment: Sorry for the fuzzy previous comment , so to answer your question you need to define for ETC a separate Folder using datadir

Answer (score 1):

For Ethereum Classic, run `parity --chain classic`. See `parity --help`:

```
--chain CHAIN            Specify the blockchain type. CHAIN may be either a
                         JSON chain specification file or olympic, frontier,
                         homestead, mainnet, morden, classic or testnet
                         [default: homestead].
```

It's also interesting to see that parity also allows to run in frontier mode. So if anyone is strictly against any hardfork, they should mine the `--chain frontier`. ;-)